# Method was called on null for calculation method....result required

Tags: flutter, dart, calculator

*edit 2 solved - my issue was with how I was calculating and passing the cost variable. Used a void method for calcBase and retrieved using the proper writing of the `of` method and updated how I was running the calculation:

DataPageState class

```
void calcBase() {
    setState(() {
      int rng = min + r.nextInt(max - min);
      romRandom = (rng / 100.0);

      final selectedBlValues =
          blValues[dropDown];
      if (selectedBlValues != null) {
        rom = (dL * selectedBlValues[0] +
            (wL * selectedBlValues[1]) +
            (cC * selectedBlValues[2]) +
            (mT * selectedBlValues[3]));
      }

      cost = (rom * romRandom).toInt();
    });
}

  static DataPageState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<DataPageState>()!;
  }
```

Calculate class

```
DataPageState.of(context).calcBase();
var cost = DataPageState.of(context).cost;
```

*edit to include error being received:

> ======== Exception caught by gesture =============================================================== The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The
> method 'calcBase' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> calcBase()

Trying to write what I thought should be a fairly straight forward calculator type application in Flutter with Dart. When I only had one page there were no difficulties in displaying the result of the calculation I am trying to return the result of based on user input. The user input is multiplied by data held within the app. Now that I am trying to pass the result to another page I am running into errors. At this moment when the 'Calculate' button is pressed the error being thrown is:

The method 'calcBase' was called on null. From what I can understand it is because the object has not been initialized. I am not a developer, only thought I could help with a little project while it was slow at work, and I think using AI has muddied the waters for me even more.

I have multiple files trying to achieve the desired results. The data_input.dart file is where I would like the user to input their variables that will be used to calculate the result based on some variables that are held within the DataPageState class written in this file. The user would then hit the 'Calculate' button on this page which I would like to trigger the 'Calculate' class written in the calculate_button.dart file. Then finally display the result in the 'ResultPage' class for the user. But since the method 'calcBase' which is housed in the data_input.dart file is apparently being called on null it is showing the overlay I want to be shown then routing directly back to the 'DataPage' class.

It seems the fix shouldn't be too difficult, but after reading multiple threads and trying to use AI as an aide I am more confused than normal. Any help to understand how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

data_input.dart

```
class DataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DataPageState createState() => DataPageState();
}

class DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
  int cost = 0;

  String dropDown = '48';
  String user = '48';
  String selected = '';

  List<String> values = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
  ];

  void getDropDownItem() {
    setState(() {
      selected = dropDown;
    });
  }

  // for UI
  var dL = 0;
  var wL = 0;
  var cC = 0;
  var mT = 0;

  // to hold base data
  final baseValue = const [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
  ];
  //Holds base lay values at positions [0]blDL, [1]blWL, [2]blCC, [3]blMT
  final Map<String, List<int>> blValues = {
    '1': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    '2': [50, 60, 70, 80],
    '3': [90, 100, 110, 120],
    '4': [130, 140, 150, 160],
    '5': [170, 180, 190, 200],
    '6': [210, 220, 230, 240],
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/ppLogo.png',
              height: 65.0,
              width: 200.0,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            flexibleSpace: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned.fill(
                    child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/inApp.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black26,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 16.0,
                  horizontal: 32.0,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 0.0, top: 8.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 24.0),
                              labelText: 'Drop Down Values'),
                          value: dropDown,
                          items: values
                              .map((String value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(value),
                                  ))
                              .toList(),
                          onChanged: (data) => setState(() {
                                dropDown = data!;
                                getDropDownItem();
                              })),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          dL = int.parse(val);
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "DL",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter Your DL Value",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          wL = int.parse(val);
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "WL",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter Your WL Values",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          cC = int.parse(val);
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "CC",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter Your CC Value",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 24.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          mT = int.parse(val);
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "MT",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter Your MT Value",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Calculate(),
                    const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 0.0, top: 8.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Text.',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Container(color: Colors.black26),
          )
        ],
      ),
      //floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNav(),
    );
  }

  // This function calculates the base lay cost.
 int calcBase() {
    // Calculation based on the values that the user has entered in the TextFields.
    num cost = 0;

    // Get the values from the DataPage class.
    String dropDown = DataPageState.of(context).dropDown;
    var dL = DataPageState.of(context).dL;
    var wL = DataPageState.of(context).wL;
    var cC = DataPageState.of(context).cC;
    var mT = DataPageState.of(context).mT;

    // Calculate the base for each category.
    num dLB = blValues[dropDown]![0] * dL;
    num wLB = blValues[dropDown]![1] * wL;
    num cCB = blValues[dropDown]![2] * cC;
    num mTB = blValues[dropDown]![3] * mT;

    // Add the base for each category to get the total cost.
    cost = dLB + wLB + cCB + mTB;

    return cost.toInt();
  }
  static of(BuildContext context) {
  }
}
```

calculate_button.dart

```
class Calculate extends StatelessWidget {
  const Calculate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> showOverlay(BuildContext context) async {
    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
        opaque: true,
        builder: (context) =>
            Center(child: Image.asset("assets/images/pipeSqueak.gif")));

    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);

    return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
      overlayEntry.remove();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
        builder: (buttonContext) => ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey[600]!),
              foregroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red[900]!),
              shadowColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.lightGreen[400]!),
            ),
            //child: const Text('Calculate'),
            onPressed: () {
              showOverlay(context);
              var cost = DataPageState.of(context).calcBase();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          ResultPage(cost: cost),
                    ),
                  );
              },
          child: const Text('Calculate'),
        ));
  }
}
```

result_page.dart

```
class ResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int cost;

  const ResultPage({Key? key, required this.cost}) : super(key: key);


  void customLaunch(command) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(command)) {
      await launchUrl(command);
    } else {
      throw 'Unable to complete $command';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            title: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/Blank.png',
              height: 0.0,
              width: 0.0,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
            flexibleSpace: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned.fill(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/resultAppBar.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
            color: Colors.black26,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 16.0,
                horizontal: 22.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                  const Text(
                    'Text:',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '$cost',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
                  ),
                 
//Remaining code is text
```

I have tried using some AI applications to help rectify the issue along with reading various threads on multiple sites and watching a few videos. I am not fully convinced the issue I think I'm facing is actually the issue that I am facing.

Comment: When asking about a specific error, it is useful to show the message of the given error, and hopefully, the stack trace tells exactly what component is causing the issue. With all of this code is a bit hard to tell.

Comment: This appears to be the only error being thrown that I can see.
'''
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'calcBase' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: calcBase()
'''
From what I am able to understand I am either not writing the calculation properly, or it is calculating properly but the variable is not being passed the whole way along. I've tried GlobalKeys and a couple other ways to get the cost variable to pass properly, but it seems I am missing something.

Comment: Edit your question, and add the error message (or print it. 
While you are trying to understand your error, try to "deconstruct" your app, by commenting partially some code, until you discover exactly what element is creating the error.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Canilho. I really appreciated the feedback.